# Firebase Firestore Security Rules 'request.auth.ui' not equal to 'KullaniciId'

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying write rules for my firebase firestore. But it's not working and return 'Simulated write denied'. What sholud i do. I add screenshots below;[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the database structure in Firestore?

Answer (score 1):

You have your location to create document set to `/Users/{KullaniciId}` and the UID is `XnLOSW.....` so that `if` statement is actually `'KullaniciId' == 'XnLOSW...'`. Change your location to:

```
/Users/XnLOSW...
```

Now `{KullaniciId}` will have the value from your location and should pass the rule.